# React.js + Summernote, how to import JavaScript dependency libraries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, summernote

I am new to React.js and I want to use a specific WYSIWYG editor - Summernote as a component.

I am using

- React v16.2.0
- [react-summernote](https://github.com/summernote/react-summernote) v2.0.0 (*dependency*: **jQuery and Bootstrap**)

### What I tried:

As the **react-summernote** documentation suggests I did the following:

1. Installed react-summernote
2. Added following (below) to `\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\webpack.config.js`

   ```
    ...
    ...
    plugins: [
       new UglifyJSPlugin(),
       new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          $: "jquery",
          jQuery: "jquery"
       })
    ]
   ```
3. In my component (in `WYSIWYG.js`) I did the following

   ```
    // WYSIWYG.js 
    import React, {Component} from 'react';

    import ReactSummernote from 'react-summernote';
    import 'react-summernote/dist/react-summernote.css'; // import styles

    // Import bootstrap(v3 or v4) dependencies 
    import 'bootstrap/js/dist/modal';
    import 'bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown';
    import 'bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip';
    import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';`
   ```

My package.json dependency

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "react-summernote": "^2.0.0"
  },
```

### Error am getting: (in Browser)

[image: $not defined]

And nothing important in CLI. Also I tried putting `import $ from "jquery";` in my component `WYSIWYG.js`. I tried [THIS(github problem page)](https://github.com/summernote/react-summernote/issues/22) too. But same problem persists.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Did you add `jquery` as a dependency (did you run `npm install jquery`)?

Comment: Yes I did, i will also add package.js file here in a min

Comment: Why are you adding it to `\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\webpack.config.js`?

Comment: In the react-summernote documentation it says: **Add ProvidePlugin to your webpack config**. Is it a different file?

Comment: You have to add it to *your* webpack file, not the one inside `webpack-dev-server`. Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: Yes am using create-react-app. I dont know webpack. So do I have to create some file and then add it? Or is it available somewhere?

Comment: create-react-app does not expose webpack module for you to edit. Try this: https://github.com/kevgathuku/react-bootstrap-jquery/pull/1/files

Comment: Oh wow it worked! Thanks @BoyWithSilverWings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes am using create-react-app.

`create-react-app` does not expose the webpack files for you to edit unless you eject. Another way you can use to set jQuery to the window is to follow:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
// Bootstrap JS relies on a global varaible.
// In ES6, all imports are hoisted to the top of the file
// so if we used `import` to import Bootstrap, it would
// execute earlier than we have assigned the global
// variable. This is why we have to use CommonJS require()
// here since it doesn't have the hoisting behavior.
window.jQuery = $;
require('bootstrap');
```

https://github.com/kevgathuku/react-bootstrap-jquery/pull/1/files

Answer (score 0):

It's works for me.

Create a js file to include your globals
//globals.js import jquery from 'jquery'; window.jQuery = jquery; window.jquery = jquery; window.$ = jquery;

then in your component js file
import "../globals"; import ReactSummernote from 'react-summernote'; import 'react-summernote/dist/react-summernote.css';

Resource:
https://github.com/summernote/react-summernote/issues/22